# missing send invoice by email , print, confirm sales and cancel button bar in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have no clue whats happening but , I was trying to configure outgoing email client in Email settings under in developers mode. I  came back to quotations page all of a sudden the entire bar is missing, i cant locate Send email, confirm sale, print and cancel button at all. Any one has any clue how do I fix the view? I am using Odoo 9

Here is the image to see what I mean.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLg1.png)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Please get latest upgrade from github.
I think it's helpful for. 
try this [link](http://132308-9-0-ed507e.runbot8.odoo.com/web)

default password of odoo